# Import works in python but not in django

Tags: python, django

I have read a few dozen questions about `ImportError` but none of them address my issue specifically.

I have the following structure:

```
.
├── apps
│   ├── accounts
│   ├── core
│   ├── apimanager
│   ├── utils
│   ├── modules
│   │   ├── companies
│   │   └── products
├── assets
│   ├── apps
│   └── libs
├── fabfile
│   └── env
├── project
└── templates
```

All directories do have `__init__.py`.

Running `python`:

```
>>> from apps.modules import companies
>>> companies
<module 'apps.modules.companies' from 'apps/modules/companies/__init__.pyc'>
>>> 
>>> from apps import modules
>>> modules
<module 'apps.modules' from 'apps/modules/__init__.pyc'>
>>> 
>>> import apps
>>> apps
<module 'apps' from 'apps/__init__.pyc'>
```

Running `python manage.py shell`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  ...
  File "../django/apps/accounts/models.py", line 8, in <module>
    from apps.modules.companies.models import Company
ImportError: No module named modules.companies.models
```

If python interpreter can import all the packages/sub-packages, then Django should be able to do the same.

What am I missing?

Comment: Check the differences in their `sys.path`

Comment: @RafaelCardoso the only difference is the first item; in `python` the first item is `''` while in `./manage.py` it's the project root directory.

Comment: are you running both from the same directory?  go down one from where manage.py is and invoke it with ../manage.py shell.

Comment: @joelgoldstick yeah both from the same directory. I have tried what you mentioned just now, same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Opened a ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24889) about this issue being a possible bug. The answer I have got:

> I suspect the problem is that your "apps" module is conflicting with
>   "django.apps". Django is trying to import "from
>   apps.modules.companies.models import Company" relative to
>   "django.apps". Not sure if Django can do anything about this.

So renaming `apps` to something else is the solution.